# How to get type from <class 'int'> Python

Tags: python

I created a dictionary like this:

```
_dict = {'area_id': int,
 'area_cityId': int,
 'area_title': str,
 'area_ar_title': str,
 'area_charges': float,
 'area_venId': int}
```

when I get the dict values in loop it's give me values like this:

```
for i,j in _dict.items():
    print(i, j)

output = 
area_id <class 'int'>
area_cityId <class 'int'>
area_title <class 'str'>
area_ar_title <class 'str'>
area_charges <class 'float'>
area_venId <class 'int'>
```

what I want is:

```
area_id int
area_cityId int
area_title str
area_ar_title str
area_charges float
area_venId int
```

I can use split and replace method to get int or str from values but I wanna know if there is an other way to get output like this.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `print(i, j.__name__)`?

Comment: can you not just use the strings `"int"` etc in the first place?